# Sum of 5 normal distributions

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

what would be a correct solution to following problem:

The medical costs per patient are normally distributed with a mean equal to 7 euro and a variance equal to 49. Compute the probability that the medical costs for five patients are more than 21 euro.

a) Linear transformation
$$
X \sim N(7, 49),\hspace{.1cm} X \sim \text{med. cost for one patient}
$$
$$
Y = 5X, \hspace{.1cm} Y \sim \text{med. cost for five patients}
$$
then $E(Y) = 5\cdot7 = 35$, and $Var(Y) = 5^2 \cdot 49 = 1225$

so $P(Y>21) = P\left(Z> \frac{21-35}{\sqrt{5^2 \cdot 49}}\right) = P(Z >-0.4) = \Phi(0.4) = 0.66 $

b) CLT

$S_5 = \sum_{i = 1}^{5} x_i $

$P(S_5> 21) = P\left(Z >\frac{21-35}{\sqrt{5 \cdot 49}}\right) = P(Z > -0.89) = 0.81$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: The CLT neither applies nor is needed to solve this exercise.

Comment: You need to distinguish the random variable for each patient's cost; they cannot all be $X$, since that would imply they all had the same cost.

Comment: There is a difference between the distributions of $5X$ (five times one subjects' cost) and $S = X_1+X_2+\cdots + X_5,$ (the sum of five independent costs). // $V(5X) = 25V(X) = 25\sigma^2$ and $V(S) = 5\sigma^2.$

Comment: Yes, exactly @BruceET that is the question, in this situation it makes more sense the $S = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_5$. Thanks fot all replies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should really have a self study tag and even if it has not, the answer cannot be complete.

Now from Wikipedia we can learn, how sums of normally distributed values are distributed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

> This means that the sum of two independent normally distributed random variables is normal, with its mean being the sum of the two means, and its variance being the sum of the two variances

In your above attempt at solving this you computed the new mean as $5\times 7$ and the new variance as $5^2\times 49$. Now which of these computations does what the Wikipedia tells you to do and which one does not?

**Edit after @JakubL 'S comment under this answer:**

You are correct now. If you use R, you can easily simulate that like this:

```
> n <- 1000000  
> cost <- replicate(n, sum(rnorm(n = 5, mean = 7, sd = sqrt(49))))
> sum(cost > 21)/n
[1] 0.814186
```

And if we use $Y$ follows $N(5\times 7, 5\times 49)$ the result is the same:

```
> pnorm(21, 5*7, sqrt(5*49), lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.8144533
```

Comment: OK, sorry, it's my first post here. I added the study tag. My confusion is that my solution is (b), while the suggested solution by a teacher is (a). And the biggest issue is whats the difference between Y = 5X and Y = sum x_i. In both cases they have similar means but different variances(5^2 x 49 and 5 x 49). I have similar intuition as @Glen_b that Y = 5X takes the same cost for every patient, but we rather have to sum iid r.v., i.e. Y = sum x_i. Hence the right solution would be P(Z<0.89) = 0.81 (I realise CLT is not needed, we just have to sum 5 nor.dist which would give us Y ~ (5*7, 5*49)

Comment: @JakubL That is now correct. I have added code for simulation to confirm the result. If this answer was helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: @JakubL A terminology issue: You're not summing 5 *distributions* (whether you mean pdf or cdf, the result would not be a distribution), you're computing the distribution of the sum of 5 random variables. It's the variables that are being summed, not their distributions. (Indeed, because of the independence assumption the operation you'd be performing on the component-pdfs is *convolution*.)

Comment: Yes, good clarification. It is sum of 5 random variables following normal distribution.